# _csv.Error: sequence expected [Python]

Tags: python, csv

Here's the entirety of my code:

```
import csv

def numbersOut():
    for i in range (1, 1001):
        out.writerow("%s" % (i+1, ))
        out.writerow("\n")

csvname = raw_input("Enter desired filename: ")
headers = ["ID", "Student", "Grade"]

out = csv.writer(open(csvname + ".csv","w"), delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
out.writerow(headers)
out.writerow(numbersOut())
```

And the section that's throwing up the "sequence expected" error is line 14, namely this one: `out.writerow(numbersOut())`

Basically, what I'm trying to do is use the function `numbersOut()` to put 1000 rows in a CSV file, each with it's own ID (Line 1 (Minus headers) will = 1, Line 2 will = 2, etc). I managed to get them all on one row by using range, but that's not what I'm needed.

However, I keep getting an error when trying to use my function. I'm not sure if it's a problem with how I'm calling it or whether it's a problem within the function itself.

Any ideas? If anything needs clarifying, please ask; I have a habit of not making much sense.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Traceback, as requested:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "writer.py", line 14, in <module>
   out.writerow(numbersOut())
_csv.Error: sequence expected
```

Comment: It also might be helpful if you post the traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, if a function falls off the end without returning, it is assumed to return `None`.  Your `numbersOut()` function doesn't `return` anything. So, when you write

```
out.writerow(numbersOut())
```

you end up calling `out.writerow(None)`.  This will give you the error you're seeing, as `None` isn't a sequence and the `csv` module doesn't know how to write out `None` as a row of CSV data.

I think you would be better off declaring `numbersOut` to take `out` as an argument:

```
def numbersOut(out):
    for i in range (1, 1001):
        out.writerow("%s" % (i+1, ))
        out.writerow("\n")
```

and then call it using

```
numbersOut(out)
```

---

There are another couple of changes I'd recommend making.

If you only want to write a single value to a row, replace the line

```
        out.writerow("%s" % (i+1, ))
```

with

```
        out.writerow(["%s" % (i+1, )])
```

(note the inserted `[` and `]`).
`writerow` takes a sequence of values and writes each value out into a separate comma-separated cell.  If you pass a single string, that gets interpreted as a sequence of characters,  and each character ends up in its own cell.

Secondly, I'd recommend removing the line `out.writerow("\n")`.  When you write a row using `writerow`, the `csv` module will output the end-of-line for you.  There's no need for you to end the lines manually.  In fact, the line `out.writerow("\n")` ends up writing a cell containing a newline between each row that contains a number.

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
import csv

def numbersOut():
    for i in range (1, 1001):
        seq=[i,i,i,i]
        out.writerow(seq)
        out.writerow("\n")

csvname = raw_input("Enter desired filename: ")
headers = ["ID", "Student", "Grade"]

out = csv.writer(open(csvname + ".csv","w"), delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
out.writerow([headers])
out.writerow([numbersOut()]) # writerow() expects a sequence a list or a tuple.
```