# Python csv module throws "Error: sequence expected" at writer.writerow

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I use psycopg2 to connect postgresql and python, and here's my script,

```
import sys

#set up psycopg2 environment
import psycopg2

#driving_distance module
query = """
    select *
    from driving_distance ($$
        select
            gid as id,
            start_id::int4 as source,
            end_id::int4 as target,
            shape_leng::double precision as cost
        from network
        $$, %s, %s, %s, %s
    )
"""

#make connection between python and postgresql
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'TC_routing' user = 'postgres' host = 'localhost' password = '****'")
cur = conn.cursor()

#count rows in the table
cur.execute("select count(*) from network")
result = cur.fetchone()
k = result[0] + 1

#run loops
rs = []
i = 1
while i <= k:
    cur.execute(query, (i, 1000000, False, False))
    rs.append(cur.fetchall())
    i = i + 1

h = 0
ars = []
element = list(rs)
while h <= 15:
    rp = element[0][h][2]
    ars.append(rp)
    h = h + 1

print ars
conn.close()
```

the output is fine,

```
[0.0, 11810.7956476379, 16018.6818979217, 18192.3576530232, 21507.7366792666, 25819.1955059578, 26331.2523709618, 49447.0908955008, 28807.7871013087, 39670.8579371438, 42723.0239515299, 38719.7320396044, 38265.4435766971, 40744.8813155033, 43770.2158657742, 46224.8748774639]
```

but if I add some lines below in order to export results to the csv file, I got this error,

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
    for row in ars:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

---

```
[0.0, 11810.7956476379, 16018.6818979217, 18192.3576530232, 21507.7366792666, 25819.1955059578, 
26331.2523709618, 49447.0908955008, 28807.7871013087, 39670.8579371438, 42723.0239515299, 38719.7320396044, 38265.4435766971, 40744.8813155033, 43770.2158657742, 46224.8748774639]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Heinz/Desktop/python_test/distMatrix_test.py", line 54, in <module>
    writer.writerow(row)
Error: sequence expected
```

How to fix this？

I am working with python 2.7.6 and pyscripter under Windows 8.1 x64. Feel free to give me any suggestion, thanks a lot!

Comment: Will you please provide full traceback?

Comment: Why are you opening as bytes (binary) file? A csv file is a text file.

Comment: maybe duplication with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396284/csv-error-sequence-expected-python

Comment: @Trimax: In Python 2.x, you must use "rb" and "wb" for `csv` file IO.

Comment: @Lafada I have added full traceback in my post.

Comment: @Trimax I know the rule in python 2.x, but I tried to use 'w', I can still get rational output, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  import csv

  with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
     for row in ars:
         writer.writerow(row)
```

`ars` is just a single list. So your for loop does not extract a row from `ars`. It takes an element from the `ars` list and tries to write it as a row.

Try replacing it with

```
     for row in ars:
         writer.writerow([row])
```

This will write each element as a row in csv file.

or if u want to have a single row as in output then just dont use for loop ,instead use

```
   writer.writerow(ars)
```